# Changing the Bootstrap menu bar button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to change the size of the bootstrap navbar hamburger icon in order for visitors to actually being able to see it, but I didn't manage to do that. Does anyone know what should I do?

By The way, I use the latest version of bootstrap, HTML 5 and CSS 3. I prefer not having to use any js or other languages in order to change the size of the button.

Comment: Please post your code. "I use the latest version of bootstrap" .. exactly which one, the latest 4.x or 5.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap icon size can be change by css :- `font-size` property.